# Can't find toolbar. Android Game Development Extension for Visual studio

Tags: android, visual-studio-2019

I try to run the sample project of **Android Game Development Extension**.

I follow the step from this website: https://developer.android.com/games/agde/quickstart

When I try to install NDK by **using the SDK Manager, which is located in the extension toolbar of Visual Studio**, but I can't find the toolbar.

[I am sure that I have intalled the extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ojDo.png)

Can someone tell me where can I find the toolbar or did I do something wrong?
I am using visual studio 2019 16.11.7

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. For some reason that menu has no options, so it doesn't appear under Extensions.

What I did to solve the issue was:

1. Go to Extensions > Customize Menu...
2. Switch to the Toolbars tab
3. Check Android Game Development Extension

Now the extension toolbar buttons should appear alongside the other

[image: Toolbar]